# Running a script as Grub boot option

Tags: shell-script, scripting, grub

I'm assembling some DR stuff for my Linux boxes. One item that would be really handy would be a GRUB option that would run a script to change my boxes from static IPs to dynamic.

I know we could do a single user mode, run a script, reboot, etc but it would greatly simply things for the other admins (mostly with a Windows background) to select one item and have it complete the process automatically.

I would swear that I've seen configuration settings provided to let Grub do this at one point or another but it's been a while. Not sure what to google for.

EDIT:

I'm aware of the rc.local method, however I don't want this to run on every boot. I want there to be an option listed (line item in grub.conf, probably) which allows for a specific script to be run only when that boot option is selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grub itself can't do this. Its filesystem drivers only support reading.

You can make an entry that loads a Linux kernel (and initrd or initramfs as appropriate) and runs a specific command by passing `init=/path/to/script` on the kernel command line. That script would do all the requisite mounting, user prompting, file modifications, and finally reboot.

You can also make separate entries that pass a custom argument on the kernel command line. Unknown arguments are ignored, the assumption being that it may be used by some driver which is perhaps loaded as a module. So make Grub entries that pass a kernel argument `local.network_interfaces=…`, and in `/etc/rc.local`, look up the value of that argument (`</proc/cmdline tr ' ' '\n' | sed -n 's/^local.network_interfaces=//p'`).

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way to avoid a kernel panic when the script exits using the init method?

Comment: @TimBrigham Yes: don't exit. Either `exec` (`exec /sbin/init`, probably) or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Let the kernel setup network

```
set netcfg='ip=none'
menuentry 'Switch DHCP on/off' {
   if [ $netcfg = 'ip=dhcp' ]; then
      set netcfg='ip=off'
   else
      set netcfg='ip=dhcp'
   fi
   echo Setting $netcfg
   sleep 1
}
menuentry 'Linux' {
   linux vmlinuz $netcfg
}
```

Comment: Where would one place this?  `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`??  Is anything needed to determine/select which filesystem `linux vmlivuz` will be found on?  (I'm fairly grub-naive, so please pardon me if this seems obvious... happy to be pointed at documentation somewhere, too.)