# Where can I install systemd service that executes zsh script as early as possible

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, serial-port, gpio

I am wondering where can I install this service that executes zsh script to **run my script as soon as possible**.

Script uses serial port at /dev/ttyS5 and gpio pins.

Is there a earlier target than `multi-user.target` that can still run zsh script?

```
[Unit]
Description=Acer projector control
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/ff.zsh -a acer
ExecStop=/usr/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/ff.zsh -rb acer
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
TimeoutSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**UPDATE 2.**

```
[Unit]
Description=Acer projector control
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target
After=systemd-modules-load.service
Before=sysinit.target
ConditionPathExists=/dev/ttyS5
Before=shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/ff.zsh -a acer
ExecStop=/usr/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/ff.zsh -rb acer
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s
TimeoutSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Comment: This might give you some insights: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625605/run-a-binary-file-via-systemctl/625670#625670

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, but I need it to run as fast as possible, it helps with binary tho!

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question a bit or add some details - as the question stands now it's a bit unclear what are you actually trying to achieve..

Comment: Sorry! I hope it's now more clear

Comment: `WantedBy=multi-user.target` normally defines a system-state where all network services are started up and the system will accept logins, but a local GUI is not started. Is that _'early'_ enough?

Comment: Okay but this network services contain gpio pins or serial port? Because that's not early enough. I don't need GUI or network connection for this script

Comment: Oh that's a great idea! Could you please post an answer on how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a script as Grub boot option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/running-a-script-as-grub-boot-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When considering this, you should refer to the chart in `man 7 bootup`, that describes the overall structure of `systemd`-based boot process.

You could specify `WantedBy=sysinit.target`, but then you'll need to specify a couple things in the `[Unit]` section:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target
After=systemd-modules-load.service
Before=sysinit.target
```

and maybe also

```
ConditionPathExists=/dev/ttyS5
```

Setting `DefaultDependencies` to `no` allows your service to run earlier in the boot process, but also requires you to be more explicit about your service's requirements.

Since the script is in `/usr/local` (which could be a separate filesystem), you'll have to ensure the filesystem is mounted before trying to execute your script. That can be achieved with `After=local-fs.target`.

You'll also have to ensure the kernel modules for your `/dev/ttyS5` and your GPIO are loaded, unless your script is actively loading them. `After=systemd-modules-load.service` aims to achieve that, assuming that you've already used a `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf` file to specify the appropriate modules. You could also run `systemctl list-units *.device`, find the `.device` units corresponding to your `ttyS5` and/or your GPIO (if one exists) and set your service to run `After=` them.

If it turns out `Before=sysinit.target` is too early for your script (or `zsh`) to function correctly, then you could try `WantedBy=basic.target` and `Before=basic.target` instead.

---

Or if "between `local-fs.target` and `sysinit.target`" is not early enough for you, then you'd have to write a `initramfs-tools` hook script (to be placed into `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks`) to package your script and everything else it might need into initramfs at `update-initramfs` time, and change your current script into an *initramfs-tools boot script* (to be placed into one of the `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/*/` directories).

I would recommend not bloating the initramfs with the `zsh` shell and its requirements, though: if you want to go to the initramfs route, you should first make your boot-time script runnable with `/bin/dash` (a lightweight POSIX shell)  instead, since that's the default shell present in initramfs in modern Debian/Ubuntu.

Both the hook script and the boot script have specific requirements that need to be followed: `man 7 initramfs-tools` has examples on both types of scripts.

You'll also need to deal with the fact that during initramfs, all devices may not have been initialized yet: `udev` will be busy creating devices as kernels modules are being loaded. Your hook script would have to ensure the drivers for your `/dev/ttyS5` and your GPIO will be included in the initramfs, and your boot script would have to either explicitly load them or check that they've been autoloaded before attempting to use the devices.

Comment: Does it have to be shell script with that interesting second ```initramfs``` solution? Could it be maybe a C program? Anyway thanks for a great explanation I got a bigger picture of ```systemd``` now!

Comment: ...and I tested first solution, it works so far the earliest I got this script to run with systemd! After ```systemd-analyze plot``` analysis it fires up 5.3s after kernel starts loading vs. 13.5s with original setup.

Comment: So the second solution seems advanced to me. If I got it right kernel itself loads 1.8s so I could get this script to fire up between this times? Best case scenario I could get max. 5.3s?

Comment: Yes, getting your script (or a C program) to run within initramfs is quite a bit more tricky than running a script as part of the regular post-initramfs startup. But if you want to try it, a C program that has very little external dependencies might even be easier to include into initramfs than a zsh script. You might get somewhere in between 1.8 and 5.3 seconds; without knowing exactly what your script does it'll be impossible to guess how much you might gain by moving it into initramfs.

Comment: Okay, I think I am happy with the first solution, thanks!